# TideSDK Windows PDO exception - driver not found

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo, tidesdk

I've successfully created a TideSDK project on my Mac - packaged OSX and it worked fine.

I now need to get a windows version, so I downloaded and installed TideSDK on a PC (windows 7), but when I try and run my app, as soon as it trie to connect to the sqlite database it crashes with a warning: 
"PDO exception - could not find driver"

I've searched the web for the last 7 hours with no joy.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as my application is useless unless I can get a windows version.

Many thanks

UPDATE: Come on someone, this is driving me mad, someone else must have used Tidesdk on windows with sqlite database

UPDATE2: WHAT IS THE POINT OF HAVING A PROGRAM THAT DOESN'T WORK????? SURELY SOMEONE HAS USED TIDESDK ON PC WITH SQLITE DATABASES

Comment: Download the correct PDO driver for SQLite and add it to the PHP extensions directory and register it in php.ini.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Peter, but I have the PDO driver in the extension directory, and uncommented the reg in php.ini - still no joy

Comment: This is nonsensical....TideSDK state to ask questions on here, yet no one from TideSDK actually responds. I can not see how TideSDK works perfectly out go the box on Mac but on Windows doesn't support PDO. And when you try and edit the php.ini file + add the relevant extensions...still doesn't work. I've put so much work into an app which now is only working on mac </rant>